# Dialect in Chongqing and Huaihua

Tags: phrase-meaning

On a little trip, I picked up these phrases:

in 重庆：

lan gou: seems to be 怎么
lei si: seems to be 这是

In 怀化 (aka Feifa): me xiaodei seems to be 我晓得

Did I hear correctly?

Comment: “me xiaodei” sounds like 莫晓得;不晓得, which means 不知道.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lan gou` in Chongqingese should be:

> 啷个
>   lang3 go4
>   [Ĩaŋ⁴¹ ko²¹³]
>   (代) 怎么

or with er-hua:

> 啷个儿
>   lang3 ger4
>   [Ĩaŋ⁴¹ kər²¹³]
>   (代) 怎么

the second one `lei si` should be:

> 勒是
>   le2 si4
>   [Ĩe²¹ sɿ²¹³]
>   (代) 这是。

Here's Bridge saying 勒是雾都, Chongqingese for 这是重庆:

> [image]

---

In Sichuanese and Chongqingese `me` is more likely to be 没 or 莫, but Hunan might be a whole other tiger all together.

[最土、最闷骚的方言：怀化话](http://bbs.tianya.cn/post-5244-46-1.shtml) does say this though:

> 毛晓得------------------- 不知道